# How to replace OpenJDK 6 with OpenJDK 7?

Tags: 11.10, java, openjdk

Surprisingly (as OpenJDK 7 was released to general availability about 4 months ago) Ubuntu 11.10 still uses OpenJDK 6 instead of 7 by default. How do I best fix this? I'd prefer to remove OpenJDK 6 completely and let OpenJDK 7 to be the default-jdk and default-jre.

I don't want the official Oracle tarballs, I want deb repos - the standard Ubuntu way.

Comment: Somebody would have to build that into a Debian package and put it into a PPA on Launchpad. If nobody did that yet, you can either make a .deb or install the tar.

Comment: Still the case with 12.04

Comment: Year 2011 - Now Year 2012 - was this resolved really (which one was considered to be the answer `lol`? If not `i gonna write a nice wiki on this` in my question / answer.

Comment: It will be better to upgrade your system to LTS.

Comment: Visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/64329/how-to-replace-openjdk-6-with-openjdk-7

Answer (score 28):

The problem is that the `default-jre` package depends on OpenJDK 6 and most other packages have their dependencies defined as `default-jre | openjdk-6-jre | sun-java6-jre` - so until OpenJDK 7 becomes officially supported and will be used as the default version, or until all Java-dependent packages update their dependencies, you'll have to keep OpenJDK 6 around and set the OpenJDK 7 as default using `update-java-alternatives`. Example for 64-bit system:

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.6.0-openjdk 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1051 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

On 32-bit system the directory name will differ, you can find the right name using the `-l` switch. The second command may spit a lot of errors; either use `--jre` switch or just ignore errors – the script changes what it can and just ignores the rest.

One could theoretically edit the `default-jre` package to depend on OpenJDK 7, but be warned that this can cause more harm than good.

Comment: To get this to work on precise I had to ensure that for each openjdk-6 or icedtea-6 package there was a corresponding openjdk-7 or icetea-7 package, otherwise update-java-alternatives will fail to make the switch.

Comment: After installing the icedtea-7-plugin (`$ sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin`) it worked well on Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

For this, you must have both versions of jdk installed on your system. you can use apt-get to download both.

After that try,

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select the jdk you want to use.

Openjdk is sometimes unfavourable, for some of the applications.

You should also try for oracle-java or sun-java.

The link below is very useful for this purpose:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 3):

OpenJDK 7 is in the normal ubuntu repos in 11.10, if you look for openjdk-7-jre and openjdk-7-jdk and install them using apt-get/synaptic/software centre they should replace openjdk-6, if it doesn't you could remove the openjdk-6-* packages first using `apt-get purge openjdk-6-*`

Comment: openjdk-7-* packages seem to be meant to be installed side-by-side with openjdk-6-*. And if I try to remove openjdk-6-*, there are tons of packages to be removed as dependant (despite the fact I know some of those applications work perfectly with Java 7).

Comment: apparently `default-jre` still points to Java 6.

Answer (score 2):

The repo can be found here:
https://launchpad.net/~openjdk/+archive/ppa

or:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:openjdk/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

assuming you have OpenJDK installed

Comment: It seems it is not meant for 11.10.